# React AbortController Not Working with Current Code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So in my project, I have to call the same endpoint multiple times, to reduce my errors, I created a separate file, and placed all my API calls inside functions and just called those functions. The only issue I am having is that the `AbortController()` doesn't seem to be working with it, here is how I declared the functions, first I declared an intance of Axios and my methods like so, `signal` represents the signal from the `AbortController()` that I will pass down from the component that is making the API call.

```js
const requests = {
  get: (url,signal) =>
    axiosInstance.get(`${API_ROOT}${url}`, { signal }),
  JSONPost: (url, data,signal) =>
    axiosInstance.post(`${API_ROOT}${url}`, `${data}`, { signal }),
};


const GetData = {
  get: (signal) =>
    requests.get(`/GetData?`,signal),
};
```

Then inside the component which is making the API call, I am creating a new instance of the `AbortController()` and passing the signal like so:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const abortController= new AbortController();
    const {signal}=abortController;
    
    async function GetData() {
      await agent.GetData.get(signal).then(result => {
        setData(result.data);
      }).catch(err => {
        if(err.name==="AbortError"){
          console.debug("Request aborted")
        }
        console.error(err.response.data.Message)
      });
    }
    GetData();
    return () => {
      abortController.abort()
    }
  }, []);
```

But this does not seem to work, the console does not log the message and the Network tab still shows the request getting data from server. Not exactly sure what I am doing wrong here.

Also to add, in my back-end I added a wait timer to give it sufficient time to cancel the request, tried it out with Postman and it works fine. So the issue has to be with my current code as far as I am aware.

Comment: What version of axios are you using? Abort controller signals are supported in v0.22.0 and higher

Comment: @NickParsons Ah. My bad, I am on version 0.20.0. That explains why it wasn't working. Little oversight from my part as I thought I was on the latest version. Let me try and upgrade and see if that solves my issue

Comment: @NickParsons Hi. Just tried it out and you were absolutely on the dot about that one. Thanks alot.

Comment: Nice, glad it worked :)